# how to convert fractional value into decimal value in php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

i am working on probabilities i need to convert the fractional number into decimal number. as i used the '/' in my query for finding the probabilities.

code for getting the probabilities

```
<?php
$sql1=mysql_query("SELECT Deprication, 
       CONCAT(
           SUM(CASE WHEN `number of room` = '$pane1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
           '/',
           COUNT(Deprication)) AS `Probability of yes`  
    FROM expert 
    GROUP BY Deprication");
 $col1=array();
  while($u6=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
 {
 echo "<tr>";

  echo "<td></br>" . $u6['Deprication'] . "</td></br>";
    echo "<td></br>" . $u6['Probability of yes'] . "</td></br>";
    $col1[]=$u6['Probability of yes'];

}
```

now i want to convert the `1/5,1/4,1/2` into decimal.

output

```
no   1/4
yes  2/6
```

Comment: could you please show the output for echo $u6['Probability of yes']?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty solution can be like this. I'm not sure if there's any smarter solution.

```
<?PHP
 $s = "2/3";
 $a = explode("/",$s);
 echo $a[0]/$a[1];
?>
```

In your case,

```
<?PHP
 $a = explode("/",$u6['Probability of yes']);
 $v = $a[0]/$a[1];
 array_push($col1,$v);
?>
```

Comment: display error : Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\EMS3\navie.php on line 92 $v = $a[0]/$a[1];

Comment: display error:Warning: Division by zero in C:\wamp\www\EMS3\navie.php on line 92

Comment: what's the type of $u6['Probability of yes']; you can test it with var_dump($u6['Probability of yes']);

Comment: i need to divide no value 1/4=0.25 n yes value=2/6 seperately

Comment: yes it's dividing separately. it's converting every $u6['Probability of yes']; to real value. Please show me the code you added

Comment: <?php
$b=implode($u6['Probability of yes']);
 $a = explode("/",$b);
 var_dump($b);
 $v = $a[0]/$a[1];
 array_push($col1,$v);
?>

Comment: write $b=$u6['Probability of yes']; instead of $b=implode($u6['Probability of yes']);

Answer (score 0):

You should select the SUM and COUNT separately instead of selecting the concatenated result. Then you'll be able to take `($row['sum'] / $row['count'])` in your code or convert it as needed.